# How to merge two bones into one with preserved weights in Blender 2.9

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, rigify

I've seen old threads with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> solution, in documentation *armature -> merge*,  but in 2.9 both ways doesn't work. I need to - obviously - delete second shin and 2nd thigh bone. Yup, rigify.

Comment: Did you try pushing X then select "Dissolve Bones"?

Comment: It remove one bone with its weight paint data. It would be good but I need some way to merge them in a way that will not mess up my existing animations too much.

Comment: Was "Merge Bones" (alt-m) removed from Blender 2.9 onward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix my skeleton by using Vertex Weight Mix modifier.
Simply:
A=bone which should stay |
B=the other one |
Vertex set=All |
Mix mode=Add
+2nd modif for other leg and apply both

Now disconnect bones to prevent its shifting during dissolving (simply uncheck connected checkbox in edit mode)
And finally dissolve additional bone with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>